# Working with table content in IEEEtran package

Tags: tables, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am also working with the IEEE `ieeetran` package for conference papers. Got to insert a table for confusion matrix, in one column without messing with the template style.

I adopted this from a previous answer:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Confusion matrix for SVM using pooled features}
\label{tab:confusion}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\textbf{Predicted}}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\bfseries}l} *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
    \toprule
    &   &   \mcc[6]{\textbf{Actual}}                            \\
    \cmidrule{3-8}
    &   & {\textbf{Sitting}} & {\textbf{Standing}}  & {\textbf{Walking}} 
        & {\textbf{Running}}  & {\textbf{Jogging}}  & {\textbf{Precision}}\\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{\rothead{Predicted}} 
    & Sitting   & 97.13 &  1.52 &  5.17 &  0.40 &  0.58  & 97.88  \\
    & Standing  & 0.66  & 93.57 &  0.16 &  0.13 &  3.06  & 95.88  \\
    & Walking   & 95.11 & 0.89  &  1.69 &  0.45 &  0.94  & 96.28  \\
    & Running   & 1.66  & 5.10  &  0.26 &  0.50 &  91.44 & 92.42  \\
    & Jogging   &  0.92 &  2.42 &  0.40 &  0.32 & 93.11 & 95.81   \\
    \midrule
 & Recall
        & 97.13         & 93.57         & 93.82    
        & 92.82         & 93.11         &           \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But then I come across a paper also from IEEE conference (so used same template) with confusion matrices for same number of classes as mine (5), and I like their table presentation:

[image]

I spent quite a lot of time trying to redesign my table to appear exactly as theirs, but couldn't same to get it.

Comment: Are you aware that your table currently is wider than one column? You should get a warning messages about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I personally prefer a table layout with less horizontal and without vertical lines, here is how you could make your table look similar to the example shown in the question. Additionally, I also made sure, the table fits into one column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for dummy text. Do not use in real document.
 \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{Confusion matrix for SVM using pooled features}
\label{tab:confusion}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Predicted}
    \centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lc| *{5}{S[table-format=2.2]}| S[table-format=2.2]}
    \hline\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Decision Tree --}   &   \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Actual}                            \\
   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Pruned}    & {Sitting} & {Standing}  & {Walking} 
        & {Running}  & {Jogging}  & {\bfseries Precision}\\ 
    \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\rothead{Predicted}} 
    & Sitting   & 97.13 &  1.52 &  5.17 &  0.40 &  0.58  & 97.88  \\
    & Standing  & 0.66  & 93.57 &  0.16 &  0.13 &  3.06  & 95.88  \\
    & Walking   & 95.11 & 0.89  &  1.69 &  0.45 &  0.94  & 96.28  \\
    & Running   & 1.66  & 5.10  &  0.26 &  0.50 &  91.44 & 92.42  \\
    & Jogging   &  0.92 &  2.42 &  0.40 &  0.32 & 93.11 & 95.81   \\
    \hline
 & \bfseries Recall
        & 97.13         & 93.57         & 93.82    
        & 92.82         & 93.11         &           \\ 
    \hline\hline
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
    
 \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: this really helps.